# Check if packets transferred are correct

Tags: javascript, webrtc, pubnub

I am making a file transfer app with pubnub and web rtc. Since web rtc is not reliable (correct me if I am wrong here), I am trying to pass the data to the other side in some reliably way.
I have already implemented the passing of packets though it doesn't seem to work (the code is pretty big so I will post only if it is needed) I have this example of a person that has done this but I can't seem to find how does he check if the packets are correct or wrong. The example is here:
[link](https://github.com/keyosk/pubnubFileTransfer/blob/master/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

WebRTC's Datachannel is reliable by default. In fact it uses SCTP. If you don't use one of those options bellow the exchange will be reliable.

> **maxRetransmitTime**: The maximum time to try and retransmit a failed
> message (forces unreliable mode)
>
> **maxRetransmits**: The maximum number of
> times to try and retransmit a failed message (forces unreliable mode)

According to the  [W3C spec](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#rtcdatachannel)

> Not setting any of these properties results in a reliable channel.

Comment: Hello. This means that each packet leaving from one peer will reach intact the other peer without any further check?

Comment: Yes you are correct. But from a developer point of view, it's easier to say that when you're sending a Blob, an ArrayBuffer or a String, the other peer will received everything. You may lose some packets, but you won't notice it.